how does bootstrapping preserve time dependence?
Here is a classic longitudinal model in which 100 people have 20 measurements taken:
$$ y_{ij} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{ij} + \beta_2 t_{ij} + u_i + \epsilon_{ij} $$
Where:

$ i = 1, 2, ..., 100 \text{ (patient index)} $

$ j = 1, 2, ..., 20 \text{ (measurement index)} $

$y_{ij}$ the outcome variable for patient $i$ at measurement $j$

$\beta_0$ is the intercept

$\beta_1$ is the coefficient for the time-invariant covariate $x_{ij}$

$\beta_2$ is the coefficient for the time variable $t_{ij}$

$u_i$ is the random effect for patient $i$,$ u_i \sim N(0, \sigma_u^2) $

$\epsilon_{ij}$ is the error term $ \epsilon_{ij} \sim N(0, \sigma_{\epsilon}^2) $


I am interested in measuring whether $\beta_1$ or $\beta_2$ had a bigger impact on $Y$. I thin there are two ways to do this:

Standardized Coefficients : compare the relative importance of different predictors in a regression model

$$ \beta_{1,std} = \beta_1 \frac{SD(x)}{SD(y)} $$
$$ \beta_{2,std} = \beta_2 \frac{SD(t)}{SD(y)} $$
$SD()$ represents the standard deviation.

Elasticity: measures the percentage change in the dependent variable for a 1% change in an independent variable.

$$ E_x = \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} \cdot \frac{x}{y} $$
$$ E_x = \beta_1 \cdot \frac{\bar{x}}{\bar{y}} $$
$$ E_t = \beta_2 \cdot \frac{\bar{t}}{\bar{y}} $$
Where $\bar{x}$, $\bar{t}$, and $\bar{y}$ are the means of $x$, $t$, and $y$.
I can fit the original model in R, but I am not sure how to calculate the standard errors of these estimates. If this were a standard regression model (non-longitudinal) , I would have just done the standard bootstrap: sample the original data with replacement, fit the model, calculate the estimate, repeat and make a histogram of estimates. But in this case, I am not sure how to set up the bootstrap to preserve the possible time dependences within the data. For example, $Y$ could be kidney function which gets worse with time, and bootstrapping could result in random samples that show kidney function improving and worsening, whereas in reality kidney function statistically decreases with time.
I thought perhaps I could just bootstrap and take the sampling unit as the entire person. E.g.

bootstrap sample 1: (all measurements for patient_1, all measurements for patient_87, all measurements for patient 91, all measurements for patient_55,  all measurements for patient_87, etc)
bootstrap sample 2: (all measurements for patient_9, all measurements for patient_71, all measurements for patient 91, all measurements for patient_55, all measurements for patient_87, etc)
etc.

But I am not sure if this is a good idea.
Is it possible to modify the bootstrap to work in this situation?
PS: I know in time series there is a rolling window method which is used in cross validation, but I am not sure if it can be applied here.

Yes, resampling whole patients works. You need to be a bit careful that when you resample the same person twice they get counted as two different people in the bootstrap world -- you need to relabel the ids $i$ to make this happen

ok - so the same person should not be resampled twice? e.g. sample_i =  (patient_18, patient 65, patient_23, patient_18) .... in this sample, patient_18 should only be included once?

oh wait i think i understand .... I think sample_i = (patient_18, patient 65, patient_23, patient_18)  is OK since the computer does not care in the background?

You need to sample with replacement, but you need to relabel the second patient_18 as, say, patient_18A. Otherwise it will look as if patient 18 has twice as many observations.

Ah ok , i think I understand now. thank you so much

Be careful though, Bootstrapping is a non parametric technique so you cannot draw conclusions about the larger population. However, if you want to analyze the effect of a coefficient variable you could also run an ANOVA test on the regression or a t-test of the coefficients.
